# How to pass parameters to $http in angularjs?

Tags: http, angularjs, parameters

Assume that I have two input boxes with corresponding ng-model as fname and lname. If I call http request as :

```
$http({method:'GET', url:'/search', params:{fname: fname, lname: lname}})
```

will it call to the url :

```
/search?fname=fname&lname=lname
```

The error I am getting at the backend(python) is :

```
cannot concatenate str and nontype objects.
```

Are these parameters not sent as strings? If not, how to get around with this?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Here is how you do it:

```
$http.get("/url/to/resource/", {params:{"param1": val1, "param2": val2}})
    .then(function (response) { /* */ })...
```

[Angular takes care of encoding the parameters](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.3.0-beta.14/src/ng/http.js#L957).

Maxim Shoustin's answer does not work (`{method:'GET', url:'/search', jsonData}` is not a valid JavaScript literal) and JeyTheva's answer, although simple, is dangerous as it allows XSS (unsafe values are not escaped when you concatenate them).

Comment: do we put values in .then

Comment: @stevek, you pass a function to the `then` clause; that function accepts a single parameter, i.e. the response itself.

Comment: For me it requires 'parameter' field wrapping data like: $http.get(
      "/url/to/resource/", 
      {
        params: {
          parameters: {"param1": val1, "param2": val2}
        }
      }
    ).then(function (response) { /* */ })

Comment: And for PUT and POST you need to use another method signature http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31572937/add-parameters-to-query-string-when-using-put-method-with-angulars-http

Answer (score 16):

Build URL `'/search'` as string. Like

```
"/search?fname="+fname"+"&lname="+lname
```

Actually I didn't use

```
 `$http({method:'GET', url:'/search', params:{fname: fname, lname: lname}})`
```

but I'm sure "params" should be `JSON.stringify` like for `POST`

```
var jsonData = JSON.stringify(
    {
        fname: fname,
        lname: lname 
    }
);
```

After:

```
$http({
  method:'GET',
  url:'/search',
  params: jsonData
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple mathed to pass values from a route provider

```
//Route Provider
$routeProvider.when("/page/:val1/:val2/:val3",{controller:pageCTRL, templateUrl: 'pages.html'});


//Controller
$http.get( 'page.php?val1='+$routeParams.val1 +'&val2='+$routeParams.val2 +'&val3='+$routeParams.val3 , { cache: true})
        .then(function(res){
            //....
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use input data to pass it as a parameter in the HTML file w use ng-model to bind the value of input field.

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter your Email" ng-model="email" required>

<input type="text" placeholder="Enter your password " ng-model="password" required>
```

and in the js file w use $scope to access this data:

```
$scope.email="";
$scope.password="";
```

Controller function will be something like that:

```
 var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

    app.controller('assignController', function($scope, $http) {
      $scope.email="";
      $scope.password="";

      $http({
        method: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in",
        params: {email: $scope.email, password: $scope.password}

      }).then(function mySuccess(response) {
          // a string, or an object, carrying the response from the server.
          $scope.myRes = response.data;
          $scope.statuscode = response.status;

        }, function myError(response) {
          $scope.myRes = response.statusText;
      });
    });
```