# Parse.com RESTAPI&angularJS query constraints key issue

Tags: angularjs, parse-platform

I have a function which does a HTTP GET request on Parse, using the code below. (I'm using AngularJs).

```
$http({ method: 'GET',
            url: 'https://api.parse.com/1/classes/foo',
            headers:{
                "X-Parse-Application-Id": "MYPARSEAPPID",
                "X-Parse-REST-API-Key": "MYPARSERESTAPIKEY",
                "X-Parse-Session-Token": UserService.sessionToken,
            },
            params: {
                where:{"toto":{"$gt":42}}
            }       
}).success(function(data, status) {
            /* DO SOMETHING*/
        }).error(function(data, status) {
            /* DO SOMETHING */
});
```

I wrote this code using Parse' REST documentation (https://www.parse.com/docs/rest#queries-constraints)
which give this example (curl):

```
curl -X GET \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id:..............." \
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key:.............." \
  -G \
  --data-urlencode 'where={"score":{"$gte":1000,"$lte":3000}}' \
  https://api.parse.com/1/classes/GameScore
```

This is the result of the AngularJS request above seen through Chrome's Dev Tools:

```
where:{"toto":{}}
```

And this this the result of the same code, without the '$' character (it doesn't work, but the requet is sent as it should):

```
where:{"toto":{"gt":42}}
```

As you can see, the constraint disappears because of the '$' character.

I supposed angular doesn't let us use '$' as it is used for Angular properties/methods.
Any suggestion/ideas/example will be very helpful.

**Edited**:
I tried to stringify the params as RobH said, click [here](http://i1049.photobucket.com/albums/s390/Tho_Mas/parseChormConsol_zpsa724ae85.png) to look at the result seen through Chrome's Dev Tools.

The result of this query seems ignore completly the given contraints, even if the '$' caracter hasn't been striped. I found that someone else tried to stringify the params ([How to pass parameters to $http in angularjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18910054/how-to-pass-parameters-to-http-in-angularjs)), but according to the last comment, it "does not work ({method:'GET', url:'/search', stringifiedJsonData} is not a valid JavaScript literal)". I'm not sure about the relevance of this comment as I'm new at AngularJs and web in general.

Any other ideas ?

Comment: Looks like this was a known issue: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1463 have a read thru' that for workarounds. Simplest seems to be to stringify the `params` yourself first.

Comment: I finaly found why it wasn't working. The params property has to be javascript object (not a string). Instead of stringify the entire object, I only stringified my contraints which contain the '$' caracter. var myParams = { "where":myStringifiedContraint, limit:myLimit };