# Add parameters to query string when using PUT method with Angular's $http

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I'm using Angular's `$http` service to make web api requests.  When I use the GET method, the two param values are added to the query string:

```
// http://foo.com/api/test?heroId=123&power=Death+ray
$http.get("/api/test", {
   params: { heroId: 123, power : "Death ray" }
})
```

However, when I use the PUT method the params are JSON-encoded and sent as the request payload:

```
// {"params":{"heroId":123,"power":"Death ray"}}
$http.put("/api/test", {
   params: { heroId: 123, power : "Death ray" }
})
```

How can I force the params to be added to the query string when using PUT?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

With `$http.put`, `$http.post` or `$http.patch`, the *config* object containing your url parameters goes as the **third argument**, the second argument being the request body:

```
$http.put("/api/test",                                       // 1. url
          {},                                                // 2. request body
          { params: { heroId: 123, power : "Death ray" } }   // 3. config object
);
```

**`$http.put` [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#put) for reference**

Answer (score -3):

AngularJS send json data and not x-www-form-urlencoded format data.
Though you can try the below one:

```
$http.put("/api/test", { heroId: 123, power : "Death ray" });
```

Answer (score -3):

If your api url is "api/test/heroId/power",

var data = 123+'/Death ray'

**$http.put("api/test"+data);**

Comment: You must have misunderstood the question. The params go in the query string, not the path.