# Simplest AngularJS App to with Session Authentication to DRF

Tags: angularjs, django, authentication, django-rest-framework, session-cookies

I have been banging my head against the wall for far too long trying to get session authentication to work in AngularJS with the basic Django REST Framework setup. I've read through blogs dozens of stack overflow questions and answers, and I'm just not getting it. I have a large application that I'm working on, but in order to facilitate an answer to this issue, I've produced a minimalist AngularJS App on top of a fork of the bare-bones Django REST Framework Tutorial code [here](https://github.com/stephenHartzell/rest-framework-tutorial). (All the front-end dependencies are included in the fork.) Just do `pip install -r requires.txt`, `python manage.py makemigrations snippets`, `python manage.py migrate`, and then `python manage.py runserver`.

The main code of interest is here:

```js
"use strict";

var geoint = angular.module('snippets', [
  'ngRoute',
  'ngCookies',
  'ngAnimate',
  'ngResource',
  'snippets.controllers',
])

.config(function ($routeProvider, $httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
  $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
  $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';

  $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
      title:'Snippets - Home',
      templateUrl: STATIC_URL + 'snippets/partials/snippets.html',
      controller: 'SnippetsCtrl'
    })
    .otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/'
    });
})

.run(function($rootScope, $location, $http) {

    // Get a CSRF Token
    $http.get('api/auth/login/?next=/api/').then(
      function successCallback(response){
        console.log(response);
        // Post should come back with Set-Cookie sessionid, but it doesn't!
        $http.post('api/auth/login/', {username:'username', password:'password'}).then(
          function successCallback(response){
            console.log(response);
            // Get this user's information
            $http.get('api/currentuser/').then(
              function successCallback(response){
                console.log(response);
              })
          })
      },
      function errorCallback(response){
        alert(response);
      }
    );

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="pc2">
    {% load static from staticfiles %}
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title ng-bind="title">PC2</title>
        <script>var STATIC_URL = "{% static "" %}";</script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "resources/css/complete.min.css" %}">
        {% if debug %}
        <script src="{% static "resources/js/_bower.js" %}"></script>
        <script src="{% static "resources/js/app.js" %}"></script>
        <script src="{% static "resources/js/controllers.js" %}"></script>
        <script src="{% static "resources/js/directives.js" %}"></script>
        <script src="{% static "resources/js/filters.js" %}"></script>
        <script src="{% static "resources/js/services.js" %}"></script>
        {% else %}
        <script src="{% static "resources/js/complete.min.js" %}"></script>
        {% endif %}
    </head>

    <body>
        {% load static from staticfiles %}
        <div ng-include="'{% static "resources/partials/navbar.html" %}'"></div>
        <div ng-view class="container-fluid main-view"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

My nested GETs and POSTs are ugly and obviously not how I would really do this in an application. But I think it *should work*, and it doesn't. I've been using postman and chrome to figure out the problem. The root of the problem seems to be that when I use AngularJS, the POST does not come back with a Set-Cookie that includes sessionid. (When I use the browser it does.) Thus, when it tries to get the user information it doesn't have the cookie set, and it comes into Django as an AnonymousUser. Any help that anyone can offer is greatly appreciated!

So the question is **Why doesn't this work in AngularJS, but it does with the browser?** I would also appreciate input on best practices, or better ways to solve this problem. (New DRF endpoint, use $resource, etc)?

Comment: Have you tried setting the `withCredentials` flag? See e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Requests_with_credentials

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if this is your issue, but I'd look at how you're passing the username/password parameters in your POST request. Try taking a look at this thread for reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31572937/add-parameters-to-query-string-when-using-put-method-with-angulars-http

Comment: Can you provide an example of your login with angularjs ? I cloned the repository and it seems to be working fine.

Comment: jonrsharpe, that should be taken care of by `$httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;`

Linovia. when you go to localhost:8000 and look at the console output, you should see "User not found". The problem is that the final GET request in the app.js file doesn't authenticate. So I don't think it works. Note that if you manually logged in using admin or the api with the browser, then you'll get a sessionid cookie and then then the angular code will succeed.

Comment: Well I just figured something out that pushes the problem back. The issue is that the POST is not doing what I thought it was doing. It will get a 200 status code no matter what the username and password are (even if they are wrong).

Answer (score 0):

Alright, after fiddling around with this problem more this morning I got the answer. For the DRF default api login view, the data must be submitted as a form. Therefore, this ended up being the solution:

```
.run(function($rootScope, $location, $http) {
$http.get('api/auth/login/').then(function successCallback(response){
console.log(response);
$http({
    "method": "POST",
    "url": 'api/auth/login/',
    "data": $.param({username:'username', password:'password', next:'/api/currentuser'}),
    "headers": {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
}).then(
  function successCallback(response){
    console.log(response);
  })})
```

});

I would still be very interested to learn the "right" way to do this. Should I build a separate DRF login view? Should I use Angular $resource instead of $http calls? I would appreciate any and all inputs.