# How can I keep the break line in my c# api?

Tags: c#, angularjs, api

I create a `textarea` in html. In the `textarea` you can have break line. When I check, if the value returns the break line, it's good. But when I do that in my API

```
public string Put(string comment = "")
{
    return comment ;
}
```

To check again if I have the break line, there is no break line.

this is what I send to the API

```
Test
test
```

this is the response of the api

```
Testtest
```

Someone have any idea how can I resolve my issue ?

**UPDATE**

When I call my api in angularjs

```
$http.put('api/Test?comment=' + comment).then(function (response) {
    console.log(response.data)
})
```

With `console.log(response.data)` I see that my api remove break line but when I check `console.log(comment)` I see my line break.

**UPDATE**

I guess it have this is issue with the binding `String`, there is another binding or a solution for my issue ?

Comment: How do you know what the API is responding with? There's a chance that whatever you're using to visualize the result simply isn't showing the line break.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior with `return comment` I can see the api response

Comment: `$http.put('api/Test?comment=' + comment)` is your problem. You need to encode the comment for the URL context.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior how can I do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By constructing the query string yourself, you're neglecting to encode the parameters. This will not only cause problems with newlines, but with any symbols that have special meanings in the query string (e.g. `&`, `+`). It [looks like](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31573068/120955) you can do this:

```
$http.put('api/Test', {}, {params: {comment: comment}}).then(function (response) {
    console.log(response.data)
});
```

You may also want to consider passing the comment in the body of your put rather than the URL. (Depending on your server-side technology, you may need to change your server-side code to make this work.)

```
$http.put('api/Test', {comment: comment}).then(function (response) {
    console.log(response.data)
});
```