# AngularJs, Consuming REST service based on the optional parameters inserted by the user

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I want to pass optional parameters to the url based on the user input(2 Html Text Boxes) and accordingly consume the ASP.NET Web API but i don't know how.
This is my Controller

```
[Route("api/JobShow/{keyword}/{location}")]    
public class JobShowController : ApiController
{

    [HttpGet]
    public PageResult<sp_JobSearch_Result> Get(ODataQueryOptions<sp_JobSearch_Result> options, string keyword = null, string location = null)
    {
        ODataQuerySettings settings = new ODataQuerySettings()
        {
            PageSize = 20
        };

        JobWindow obj = new JobWindow();
        IQueryable results = options.ApplyTo(obj.showJobs(keyword, location).AsQueryable(), settings);
        return new PageResult<sp_JobSearch_Result>(
           results as IEnumerable<sp_JobSearch_Result>,
           Request.GetNextPageLink(),
           Request.GetInlineCount());
    }
}
```

And this is my AngularJS controller

```
angular.module('JobSearch.SiteController', []).controller('JobSearchCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

$http.get('/api/JobShow').success(function (data) {
    $scope.model = data;
});
}]);
```

Example of the url then would be .../api/JobShow/Developer/Montreal. Thank you all.

Comment: `$http.get('/api/JobShow/' + $scope.enteredKeyword + '/' + $scope.enteredLocation)`? What's the concrete difficulty? Note that if these parameters are optional, they shouldn't be part of the path. They should instead be part of the query string.

Comment: Yes parameters are optional. I did the same as you mentioned here but did't work well. What do you mean by query string here?

Comment: I mean parameters, which end up sending a request to a URL like `api/JobShow?keyword=foo&location=bar`. We can't help with your code without seeing the code, and without you telling us what the concrete problem is.

Comment: In my web api controller my base url is '/api/JobShow' and it returns all the jobs.  It also accepts two optional parameters. ex:'/api/JobShow/java' returns java jobs and '/api/JobShow/java/toronto' returns only java jobs in toronto. now in the client side i want to get the same result however the optional parameter values come from text boxes.  @JBNizet

Comment: I used this $http.get('/api/JobShow/' + $scope.titleValue+ '/' + $scope.locationValue) but now both the text boxes must be filled else i do not get any results. My question is that how to have optional parameters in angularjs. I hope this helps to make my question clear. Thanks for your time.@JBNizet

Comment: Like I said: if they're optional, they shouldn't be part of the path, but of the query string. Change your server-side mapping, and pass those values as parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18910054/how-to-pass-parameters-to-http-in-angularjs) could help you.

In your case, assuming that scope.data is the parameter you want to send ñ, it should look something like the following

```
$http.get("/url/to/resource/", {params:{"param1": $scope.data, "param2": $scope.someOtherData}})
    .then(function (response) { /* */ })...
```