# How to append dynamic query parameter in HTTP get URL in Angular JS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-1.5

I am new to angular JS. I have one controller (.js file) in which I wrote a function to make a http get call to back-end. Like below:

```
             $http({
                 url: "services/rest/1.0/project/employeeDetails",
                 method: 'GET',
                 headers: config,
                 transformResponse: function (data) {
                     var x2js = new X2JS();
                     var json = x2js.xml_str2json(data);
                     return json;
                 }
             }).success(function (response) {
                 alert("success for account details with response:"+response);
                if (response && response.siteDetailsList.errorCode == 0)
                     $scope.accountdetails = response;
             });
```

Now problem is that I need to add two query parameter to my url which I mentioned in above code snippet , so that final URL will look like this:

```
services/rest/1.0/project/employeeDetails ? param1=world & param2=hello
```

This param1 and param2 value I am getting from my HTML file's input text box. 
Any idea how we append dynamic query parameter to this URL?

Comment: i think, majke alone angular , when you put it as params, and define by GET

Comment: Take a look to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18910054/how-to-pass-parameters-to-http-in-angularjs

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass parameters to $http in angularjs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18910054/how-to-pass-parameters-to-http-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `params` config property:

```
   $http({
         url: "services/rest/1.0/project/employeeDetails",
         method: 'GET',
         headers: config,
         params: {
             param1: someValue,
             param2: anotherValue
         },
         transformResponse: function (data) {
             var x2js = new X2JS();
             var json = x2js.xml_str2json(data);
             return json;
         }
     }).success(function (response) {
         alert("success for account details with response:"+response);
        if (response && response.siteDetailsList.errorCode == 0)
             $scope.accountdetails = response;
     });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `$httpParamSerializer` service from AngularJS.

> https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$httpParamSerializer

Object:

```
var obj = {
  param1:"world",
  param2:"hello"
}
```

With the httpParamSerializer:

```
$httpParamSerializer(obj)
```

Returns:

```
param1=test&param2=world
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj = 
{
  param1:"world",
  param2:"hello"
}

$http.post("services/rest/1.0/project/employeeDetails", obj)
.then(function (response)
{
        return response`enter code here`;
},`function (error)
```

{
            return error;
   });`

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. Its very simple. We can modify $url like this way too:

```
$http({
         url: "services/rest/1.0/project/employeeDetails?param1="+value+"&param2="+value",
         method: 'GET',
         headers: config
         }
```

By using a separate "param" property is a bit tricky because parameter get sorted alphabetically by default , so we need to write code for preventing sorting if we want parameter to appear in our desired order.

Any lastly, Thanks for your prompt responses. :)