# How to send multiple parameters in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I am having trouble while passing multiple param in `http` request.

Here is the code:

```
var allData={"uid": user_id, "emp_id": emp_id, "job_id": job_id}
$http({
  url: 'msg_check.php',
  method: "GET",
  // params: {'uid': user_id, 'emp_id': emp_id, 'job_id': job_id}
  params: allData
})
.success(function(datas) {
  $scope.choices = datas;
});
```

For above code I am not getting any error in Firebug, but my webpage shows all Angular `{{somevalue}}` like this. It seems like it is breaking.

If I pass only this  `params: {'uid': user_id}` then it is working fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Open your console, and read the error message. Also, don't use success() which doesn't exist anymore, after being deprecated for a long time. Use then().

Comment: Take a look at this [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18910054/how-to-pass-parameters-to-http-in-angularjs)

Comment: Since this is an exact duplicate that has not attracted answers, it can probably be deleted.